# Detecting if "Wall" To The Left or Right Of Player Unity3D

Tags: unity, collision-detection, unityscript

I am working on a 3D Platformer in Unity3D and I need to prevent the player from going through walls. The movement for my player works like this:

[image: bird-eye-view player movement]

(A bird-eye-view representation)The areas the player can move a divided into layers. He can slide into the 2nd, 1st , or 3rd layers. The player is not a rigid-body, and is controlled using a character controller. To move the player into these layers I simply increase his Z-Axis. Currently if my player is behind the wall he will slide directly into it. How can I determine if there is a wall to the left of the player in Unity 3D? If so, I simply wont allow the user to move to the layer until they have steered clear of the obstacle. Does anyone have any suggestions of what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [CharacterController.Move](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) to detect collision to the wall. if you don't want to use Move then you can cast a ray with [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to check if wall close enough to stop your character or let him move ;)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with CharacterController.Move

function MoveTo(newPos : Vector3, controller : CharacterController) : IEnumerator
    {
     vertMoveDirection = newPos - transform.position;
     controller.Move(vertMoveDirection);

    }

However I want the movement to be smooth. Is there anyway I can do this in this function?

Comment: what's wrong with movement ?

Comment: It sort of teleports. Anyway I'll figure it out :)

Comment: Vector3.lerp could help ;)

Comment: Ended up using raycasting =)